# I can not connect to 5G/any network of wifi on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: wireless, 20.04

I can connect to wifi 5G network of my place but not any other wifi

1. I have given correct password
2. I have updated the drivers to the latest ones

Answer (score 0):

As i read your question, you can connect to a 5GHz wifi SSID you see, but cant connect to other 5GHz or 2.4GHz wifis, correct?

You should specify more about your hardware, and if you had windows installed before, if it was working then.

Often the issue with wifi can be coverage, and sometimes its the wifi chip drivers. Try moving around to get a better signal, and maybe update ubuntu using `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`